# So while the chip select is enabled, if the clock speed varies but still within the range specified, would there be spi communication?

Tags: embedded, clock, spi

While communicating with the slave will there be SPI communication if the clock speed and frequency varies?

Comment: Yes, the clock frequency can vary during an SPI transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the specification on the part should give a minimal timing requirements for the signal. But usually it give no upper limit.

That means, the time between level changes should be at least as it said in the specification, but in is not required to be at any particular frequency, or to have equal periods for different pulses. You can even pause communication by holding level unchanged for a long period of time.

Still, in some devices there may be special requirements on the frequency of pulses and it's maximal duration. For example, ADC parts can rely on SPI-clock to perform measurements. Making uneven or too long SPI clocks may have an influence upon the result.

So, the answer is: in either case carefully read the datasheet on the part you're using.